# gnus nnimap-split-methods is not splitting my mail

Tags: emacs, imap, gnus

I'm trying to use `nnimap-split-methods` to split incoming mail into different groups, but it's not working. Even with this simple split rule:

```
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods
      '((nnimap "MyMail"
        (nnimap-address "imap.example.com")
        (nnimap-server-port 993)
        (nnimap-stream-type ssl)
        (nnir-search-engine imap)
        (nnimap-inbox "INBOX")
        (nnimap-split-methods '(("mail.pizza" ".*"))))))
```

all my mail shows up in `mail.misc`. I also tried replacing `".*"` with `""` since the documentation says the last element should always be `""`. What am I doing wrong here??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I never got this working with `nnimap-split-methods` directly, but I was able to get what I wanted by using `nnmail-split-methods` and then setting `nnimap-split-methods` to `default`, like so:

```
(setq gnus-secondary-select-methods
      '((nnimap "MyMail"
        (nnimap-address "imap.example.com")
        (nnimap-server-port 993)
        (nnimap-stream-type ssl)
        (nnir-search-engine imap)
        (nnimap-inbox "INBOX")
        (nnimap-split-methods default))))


(setq nnmail-split-methods
      '(("gerrit" "X-Gerrit-MessageType.*")
        ("list.\\1" "From:.* \\(.*\\)-list@majordomo.com")
        ("list.lkml.kernel" "X-Mailing-List:.*linux-kernel@vger\\.kernel\\.org")
        ("list.linux-arm-kernel" "Cc:.*linux-arm-kernel@lists\\.infradead\\.org")
        ("mail.other" "")))
```